# TFS Check-in Rejected, MSBuild version '15.0' was not found for architecture 'x86'

Tags: xamarin, tfs, msbuild, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm unable to check-in to TFS from eclipse, during check-in each time it showing the below mentioned error.

> MSBuild version '15.0' was not found for architecture 'x86'. Verify the architecture input value is correct and verify Visual Studio 2017 is installed. MSBuild version '15.0' is included when Visual Studio 2017 is installed.

Working on mac machine with Xamarin studio and using team server from eclipse to check in code.
I'm working on Xamarin form project targeting to Android and build supporting ABIs x86,armeabi,armeabi-v7a
I don't have any Visual studio installed in my machine and how to handle this MSBuild version.

Eclipse version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)
Java version: 1.8.0_131
Mac version: OSX El Capitan(10.11.3)
Xamarin studio: 6.1.2(build 44)

Comment: Did this only occurs on this project or every project? Could you successfully check out files from TFS?

Comment: Yes i successfully checked in from other project. only in the current project i'm getting this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try below ways to narrow down the issue:

1. Give a try with check in another simple project--if the error
   related to the project or not.
2. Make sure you are using the latest [Team Explorer Everywhere](https://github.com/Microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere) --
   the official TFS plug-in for Eclipse
3. Try to check out some files from TFS or open the web portal for TFS
   to see if there are some issue with TFS connection.

Comment: i have uninstalled eclipse and upgraded to Neon.3. and also updated team explorer plugin. Only for my current project i'm getting this error. Do i need to share any other information?

Comment: @Suchith This is weird,  as far as I know there shouldn't be anything can't check in TFS. And unlike build, the check in action  is not related to the environment. (You could also check in other projects) The issue may related to the source control binding of the specific project. You could try to unbind the project and rebind the project again.

Comment: Hi , @Suchith any update on this issue, did my comment helped to figure out it or gave a right direction?

Comment: Ya Patrick, i think Unbinding the project, delete entire local folder and bind, get latest version helped.